# Scala: string pattern matching

Tags: scala, match

The below code takes the first two character of string and check if pattern is `"de" or None` it returns None else it returns the `Test("Found")`

```
val s =Option("abc")
val t = s.map(_.take(2))
case class Test(id:String)

t match {
  case Some("de") => None
  case None => None
  case _ => Test("Found")
}
```

Can anyone suggest a efficient solution for case matching

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: edited question please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you meant `Some(Test("Found"))` in the last line of your snippet, judging from your comment to the other answer. 
If so, this is what you are looking for:

```
t.filterNot(_.take(2) == "de").map(_ => Test("Found"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I get what you're asking so let me try this:

```
val condition = Option("abc").exists(_.toLower.take(2) == "de")
val output: Any = if(condition) Test("found") else None
```

The first portion returns `false` if the `Option` is `None`. It also returns `false` if the first two letters of the string are `"de"` in a case insensitive way.

The second portion returns either a `None` or a `Test` object. However, I want to point out that this results in an `Any`. Did you mean for it to return a `Option[Test]` type instead?

Comment: yes return type to be ```Option[Test]``` not ```Any```